# Multi-Site Active Directory Sync

Tags: active-directory

I have created 4 Active Directory Domain Controllers both in different locations. One is in Delhi and Another one in Mumbai.

Delhi has 2 domain controllers Primary(DDC01) and Secondary(DDC02).

Mumbai has 2 domain controllers Primary(MDC01) and Secondary(MDC02).

Both have different networks and I can take the RDP of both Domain controllers from different locations.

Now I want to connect all 4 Domain Controllers so they can replicate the data and policies.

I saw this can be done through Active Directory Site and Services.

I Added Subnet's of Both Sites in Mumbai DC i.e. MDC01

I created Sites such as Mumbai-HO and Delhi-BO in MDC01 it got replicated to MDC02.

I could see MDC01 and MDC02 but I cannot see any of the DDC01 or DDC02 showing there.

Am I missing something?

Just FYI... DDC01 and DDC02 are having different gateways due to some reason.

Answer (score 0):

•   Please check the active directory site replication ports are open between for communication between the Mumbai and Delhi sites by doing telnet from command prompt on each of the ports. The inbound as well as outbound communication from these to ports to each other sites should be successful. Please find the list of ports as below: -

1. UDP Port 88 for Kerberos authentication
2. UDP and TCP Port 135 for domain controllers-to-domain controller and client to domain controller operations.
3. TCP Port 139 and UDP 138 for File Replication Service between domain controllers.
4. UDP Port 389 for LDAP to handle normal queries from client computers to the domain controllers.
5. TCP and UDP Port 445 for File Replication Service
6. TCP and UDP Port 464 for Kerberos Password Change
7. TCP Port 3268 and 3269 for Global Catalog from client to domain controller.
8. TCP and UDP Port 53 for DNS from client to domain controller and domain controller to domain controller.

•   Check the replication status of the AD sites through the repadmin utility by running the below command on the replicating DCs in powershell: -

```
 ‘ repadmin /syncall /force ’ or ‘ repadmin /syncall /APeD ’ or ‘ repadmin /replsum ’
```

If the message replied in the powershell states that ‘Syncall terminated with no errors’, then everything is fine and you need not worry about the replication status between sites. Also, you can check the replication topology status in AD Sites and subnets where all the sites are listed whether created automatically or manually as below: -

[image: AD Sites Replication]

This will give out the replication status and issues relating to AD site replication. For more detailed information on the replication issues, execute the below command and check for replication issues on site level. This will give out the site wise information in csv format: -

```
‘ repadmin /showrepl * /csv > showrepl.csv ’
```

•   Also, please check whether Delhi site is automatically created by KCC or not, if not, then wait for at least 24 hours after the above steps revert successful status of replication. The check the ‘Cost’ parameter of replication link in the site details workspace by clicking on it. It defines the priority level of network connection sync level between the two sites. Please find the snapshot below to know the actual cost of your network connection and set it accordingly: -

[image: AD Site replication link cost]

For more information on AD site replication issues, please refer the link below: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-GB/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/common-active-directory-replication-errors

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/diagnose-replication-failures

Comment: I tried telnet on both servers and got this error on port 138. Telnet on all other ports worked fine. Could not open connection to the host, on port 138: Connect failed

In Active Directory Sites, I cannot see all the Domain Controllers. At Delhi, I can only see DDC01 and DDC02 and similar is the case with Mumbai.

I renamed the Default Site names at both Sites but still the same issue.

Comment: Port 138 enables the shared 'NTDS' directory between the domain controllers to be synced periodically with the changes on any domain controller. Thus, it is associated with the file replication service that writes the changes to each DC's default directory and therefore creates sites automatically in AD sites and subnets after replication is successful.

Comment: I checked that UDP Port 138 is already allowed in the firewall but I still could not do telnet. Does TCP Port 138 need to be enabled?

Comment: Hi, Kartik the issue persists.

Comment: Please check the event viewer logs for any errors and incidents. Also, check whether the sites added by you in AD Sites and Subnets have the correct IP subnets mentioned and correct association with the respective site created where your DCs are located.

Comment: Thanks, Kartik. The issue is resolved. I had to create new Domain Controllers and rejoin all the systems.